# Set font to whole Page in Odoo Qweb Reports

Tags: odoo

How can I set the Font in Odoo Qweb Reports?
Currently, when I develop a report in ubuntu 12.04, PDF copy of report looks good.
But, same thing if I try in ubuntu 14.04, font looks very small.
How to over come it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<div class="page" style="font-size: 18pt;font-family:Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans,Lucida Grande,Calibri;">
```

Any one of these fonts if there, it will use that Font and the font size.